# Hello UK Users! Where are you all coming from?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Just curious, I've noticed there's a lot of you! Please keep in mind that we try to keep our questions/answers region-ambiguous.

Cheers, etc!

Comment: I voted to close, as this is a regional-specific question, and also because this isn't a discussion board. On the other hand, this *is* meta; am I off-base here?

Comment: @neilfein This is a discussion board! Hence the 'discussion' tag. =] I'm just curious about the community -- it's definitely relevant to the site (i.e., the influx of region-specific questions).

Comment: @Dustin: I think that this *isn't* a discussion board, at least not [in this sense](http://www.bikeforums.net/forumdisplay.php?242-United-Kingdom). The [FAQ for Meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq) states: 

> Avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with bicycles.stackexchange.com. This is not a random discussion board, this is a place for improving our community and website!

I would think that the [discussion tag](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) is for discussing *this website*, but maybe I don't know what I'm talking about. :)

Comment: @Dustin If you add your comment below into the question (i.e. wanting to know source of traffic, as opposed to physical location), then you might just about scrape past the region specific guardians :)  There is benefit to knowing this to help promote the site.   Still, very tenuous!

Comment: @Kevin: He has a good point, things need to be looser in Meta. Just exploring the issue; this question will be a bit of a precedent for new users that are coming to the public beta. It's important we show them what questions are okay and why. Understanding our community is important. I just would rather not see questions here along the lines of "Hi, everyone, who are you?" (Which this is not.)

Comment: There's a conceptual "third site" in development for at least some of the stackexchange sites: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/third-place-chat-beta-preview/ - this is to be pitched at the chat questions like this one.

Comment: Since the above comment was posted, chat has been implemented.

Answer (score 3):

It *may* just be that:

- A lot of computer programmers work in Oxford and Cambridge.
- People in Oxford and Cambridge tend to cycle
- Computer programmer tend to be SO users so are more lickly to know about a stack exchange stie.

Comment: I think that this is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm located in Brigton, south coast of UK, infamous for some [bad cycle lanes](http://www.weirdcyclelanes.co.uk/). I'm a SO user, came to this via Area 51 (found it through random browsing).

Answer (score 0):

I think they're coming from the UK!  ;)

Comment: Har. I'm curious if they're coming from a UK forum or board, or whether someone's doing a good promotion-job over there!

Comment: @Dustin: Perhaps edit the question to ask what kind of cycling people do in their area? What about cycling facilities in [location] do they find attractive? I hope we didn't scare people off with out the discussion above!